# Custom Trimming Back button text of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

**Environments**:

I'm developing in-app locale changing support for my iOS Apps.
It's pretty hard than it sounds, because locales of controls provided with `UIKit` are tied to iOS Locale.

I could fix almost problems but one thing is remaining for now:

**The Problem**:

When we push a view controller using an `UINavigationController`.
It will automatically generates back button item with the navigation item title of the previous view controller.

However, what if the title is too long to display as  a back button, `UINavigationController` uses `Back` as a fallback title.
Automatically shorten title(Back) is tied to system locale. And it is my problem.

Can I change this behavior legally?

Answer (score 0):

I made custom `UINavigationController` and overrided `pushViewController:animated:`

```
-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                 animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UINavigationItem* current = self.topViewController.navigationItem;

    if(current.backBarButtonItem == nil){
        current.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:current.title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem* backItem = current.backBarButtonItem;
    CGFloat width = [backItem.title sizeWithAttributes:@{}].width;

    // Trimming to localized back text
    if(width > 70){
        backItem.title = [[KKCoreLocale shared] localizedStringForKey:@"Back"];
    }

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

I can't sure this is best solution, However it is legal and works charm.